# Views UI javascript is broken

Tags: javascript, 9

I discovered today that the Views UI is broken on one my sites. I'm not sure when it broke, because the Views UI is not one of the things I check after updates.
I'm currently at 9.5.3.

My Views UI logs the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable loadjs", and follows up with a bunch of other errors that I assume stem from the first one.

When I disable JS aggregation the issue goes away.

This appears to be caused by loadjs getting packaged together with shepherd.js that turns on strict mode, and loadjs not declaring the loadjs variable (to save 4 bytes?).

So as far as options go, I'm thinking:

- patching in "var " for loadjs
- patching out strict mode for shepherd.js
- disabling js aggregation for admin routes somehow

Am I missing something? How come I'm apparently the only one seeing this problem?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3336143

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a known issue on drupal.org.